# Script to download latest Adobe Reader DC Update

Tags: powershell, adobe-reader

I wrote a script download the latest version of Adobe MUI DC but I am not really happy with the parsing. The script starts at `https://supportdownloads.adobe.com/new.jsp`, followed by some parsing, getting a link to a new site, parsing and finally getting the final download link.

I am not really sure if this is the best way of doing it?

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

$download_folder = 'E:\Adobe_Acrobat_Reader_DC_MUI\'
$url = 'https://supportdownloads.adobe.com/support/downloads/'

    Write-Host "Downloading ...AdobeDC Update"
    try {
        If(!(Test-Path $download_folder)){
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$download_folder"
        }

        $download_url = $url + ((Invoke-WebRequest $url'new.jsp').Links | where outertext -like '*MUI*Continuous*' | select href).href
        Write-Host $download_url

        $download_url = $url + ((Invoke-WebRequest $download_url).Links | where outertext -like '*proceed to download*' | select outertext, href).href.replace("amp;","")
        Write-Host $download_url

        $download_url = ((Invoke-WebRequest $download_url).Links | where outertext -like '*download now*' | select outertext, href).href 
        Write-Host $download_url

        if(!(Test-Path ($download_folder + $download_url.Split('/')[-1]))){
            $webclient.DownloadFile($download_url, $download_folder + $download_url.Split('/')[-1])
        }
    } catch {
        Throw($_.Exception)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe have an [Enterprise Administration Guide](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/index.html) that is intended for businesses deploying software to multiple machines (rather than the end user themselves updating their own computer).

For [Acrobat DC](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/basics.html#latest-release-acrobat-dc) there is a section for Enterprise installers:

> Adobe provides enterprise IT with a download site that contains all available installers. Most admins download the product, updates, and patches from ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/ (or Acrobat).

That FTP link is a much easier way to get the latest version than scraping multiple websites.

You would just need to open the ftp site `ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/AcrobatDC/`, get the directory listing, pick the latest folder, and then download the `*MUI` installer.

So currently you would be downloading:

`ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/AcrobatDC/1801120036/AcroRdrDCUpd1801120036_MUI.msp`

This technique can be used for pretty much any Adobe product as they are all available: ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/

---

Out of curiosity on this I wrote a basic script to get the latest file from the ftp site:

```cs
$DownloadFolder = "E:\Adobe_Acrobat_Reader_DC_MUI\"
$FTPFolderUrl = "ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/AcrobatDC/"

#connect to ftp, and get directory listing
$FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("$FTPFolderUrl") 
$FTPRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectory
$FTPResponse = $FTPRequest.GetResponse()
$ResponseStream = $FTPResponse.GetResponseStream()
$FTPReader = New-Object System.IO.Streamreader -ArgumentList $ResponseStream
$DirList = $FTPReader.ReadToEnd()

#from Directory Listing get last entry in list, but skip one to avoid the 'misc' dir
$LatestUpdate = $DirList -split '[\r\n]' | Where {$_} | Select -Last 1 -Skip 1

#build file name
$LatestFile = "AcroRdrDCUpd" + $LatestUpdate + "_MUI.msp"

#build download url for latest file
$DownloadURL = "$FTPFolderUrl$LatestUpdate/$LatestFile"

#download file
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($DownloadURL, "$DownloadFolder$LatestFile")
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Don't know why I was not using the ftp link in the first place. I am going to change the script to work with ftp

Comment: I've just updated my answer with some basic code to get the file from ftp

Comment: uh, thank you! I still was stuck in getting the directory list into a table so that I can sort it ;)

Comment: The directory listing from `$FTPReader.ReadToEnd()` is actually a multi-line string, so needs to be put into an array before it can be sorted, `-split` is used to do this.